# Simplifying array If statements in 'if array in bigArray' manner in Python27

Tags: arrays, python-2.7

I have a gui that I run that has several checkboxes that can be selected that determine the type of test to be run. My code is currently very long an bulky and I have to list every possible combination of check boxes as a separate if statement. I have an array that I use to store my checkbox values. For each possible checkbox combo, I run a different script, but I only have a few scripts.

```
array = [var1, var2, var3]
if array == [1, 1, 0]:   
    import Test1
elif array == [0, 1, 0]:
    import Test1
elif array == [1, 0, 1]:
    import Test2
elif array == [1, 0, 0]:
    import Test2
```

I want to have my code look more like:

```
array = [var1, var2, var3]
if array in {[1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]}:
    import Test1
elif array in {[1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]}:
    import Test2
```

Is there a way to do this for arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether an array is in a list of arrays.

```
array = [var1, var2, var3]
if array in [[1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]]:
   import Test1
elif array in [[1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]]:
   import Test2
```

The reason you can't do `{[1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]}` is that this tries to create a `dict`, and Python doesn't allow `lists` as `keys`. You could however do something like:

```
array = [var1, var2, var3]
if array in {0 : [1, 1, 0], 1 : [0, 1, 0]}.values():
   import Test1
elif array in {0: [1, 0, 1], 1 : [1, 0, 0]].values():
   import Test2
```

But then you're just making the array of arrays from my first example.

Comment: It was something so simple! Thank you so much.